# Where does GarageBand put its downloaded instruments and loop libraries?

Tags: garageband

I've been using the new(ish) GarageBand on Lion for a month or so now. Early on, it prompted me to download instrument sample libraries and loops of around 1.5 GB which were not included in the initial installation. Then, it wanted a similarly-sized download to support iOS GarageBand files. I just recently found another download to enable more loops and MIDI voices.

What is the total size of all of these extra downloads, and where do they go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for total size, that is difficult to say. I got my GarageBand instrument, sample library and loop files from an iLife DVD installation a few years ago, rather than downloading them from the Mac App Store, which is the only way to get them today.

It's my understanding that when you first purchase and install GarageBand from the Mac App Store, you do not get all the musical instrument sample libraries and loop libraries that are listed in GarageBand's indexes. If you try to select an instrument or loop from an index and it is not found on your Mac, then you are prompted to download another large section of the libraries. Then there are the music lessons, which you must purchase one at a time, download and install.

My basic installation for GarageBand instruments and music lessons in ~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand is **2.74GB**.

The loops for GarageBand are stored in ~/Library/Audio/Apple Loops/, and my installation is **629.9MB**. However I do not believe that I have downloaded the whole set.

At an Apple retailer where I have worked, their installation in

- `~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` is **14.57GB**,

and their installation in

- `~/Library/Audio/Apple Loops` is **32GB**.

This includes the GarageBand-compatible instruments and loops that you get when you purchase [Apple MainStage](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mainstage/id459585276?mt=12), which you can get from the Mac App Store for $30. However, this does not include all the music lessons you can purchase within GarageBand.

Furthermore, you can purchase all sorts of Audio Unit-format effects, musical instruments, sample libraries and loop libraries from third parties that you can use within Garage Band or Logic, so you could add many hundreds of gigabytes of additional material if you want to.

It is worth mentioning that electronic musicians who work with large libraries of virtual instruments, samples and loops in GarageBand or other similar programs invariably move all such libraries to external high-speed disk drives so as not to slow down their systems with too much read-write activity on the system hard drive.

If your work with GarageBand is simple enough--not too many tracks in a mix--you can work with just your Mac and system hard drive. But if you discover that Garageband is glitching, hiccuping, or failing to record or edit correctly, or you get errors about input and output being too slow, you need to incorporate additional high-speed hard disks into your system.

It's a general principle that you need at least three hard drives:

- your system drive inside your Mac, which holds Mac OS X and the
  GarageBand app
- an external high-speed hard drive for sample
  libraries, virtual instruments and loop libraries
- another external high-speed hard drive for recording and mixing audio tracks.

All of these have to be interfaced with a high-speed interface such as FireWire 800, USB 3.0, or Thunderbolt. USB 2.0 will not work, because it is not fast enough for composing, recording and mixing music and audio.

Comment: This wasn't in my original question, but can you answer why I was prompted for the first download, the one which was required in order to run GB at all?

Comment: That's because when you buy GarageBand from the Mac App Store, you first only download a small software package that begins its installation. Then you get prompted for additional downloads to complete the installation. It's just the way that Apple chooses to manage the digital online distribution of a very large program that requires several gigabytes of files.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I had trouble getting Software Update to download the Extra Content, so I got it from this link instead:
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/43/39/061-5890/y2FxthySsyd2PSt3zfZ4mz3XkbqdGZPDZc/GarageBandExtraContent.tar

Comment: @Colin Thanks so much... I have been scouring the web for this as my installation will not grab it! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Neither of these worked for me. Mine were all located into `/Library/Audio/'Apple Loops'`, `/Library/Audio/'Apple Loops Index'`, `/Library/Audio/'Impulse Responses'`, `/Library/'Application Support'/GarageBand`, `/Library/'Application Support'/Logic`, i.e. nothing left under `~/Library` after I uninstalled GarageBand!

Comment: Can the files in the `Logic` folder be safely removed, and re-downloaded via GarageBand in the App store if I want them again?

Comment: @Winterflags Yes, this is very confusing... I have GarageBand 6.0.5, GarageBand 10.1.2, and Logic 9.1.8 all installed. It's getting really hard to manage, and when some legacy sounds, especially the "Sound Effects" for Nature, Applause, etc. go missing, and then that's what I need, I get a little frustrated. How can I back this stuff up too is really the question. Where are all the files? There are many "sets" in Logic 9 broken up differently than the Jam Packs, and way more. I've looked online, and Logic Pro X has EVEN MORE. So what's the overlap? Can this be made easy "on top of"? No...?

Answer (score 6):

The last time I looked it was in:

> /Library/Application Support/GarageBand

If they aren't there you can also try:

> ~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand

Since all the downloaded content is installed per machine, and not per user, it does make it a bit easier to backup if you don't use a Time Capsule, or otherwise to transfer these downloads between multiple machines.

I use the Learn To Play videos and when having to move them between 4 different Mac's I learned quickly where to go find them.

Comment: That's only half-right. Loops go in ~/Library/Audio/Apple Loops. See my post.